# Can I import absinthe into Australia?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, australia, alcohol

While absinthe is legal in Australia, several sources like [this Sydney Morning Herald article](http://www.smh.com.au/articles/2003/10/21/1066631424572.html?from=storyrhs) and [this article on absinthe.com.au](http://absinthe.com.au/2011/01/26/the-smoking-gun/) claim that a special permit is required for importing it from overseas.  Is this still the case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of July 13, 2013, **permits are no longer required.** [Customs has an FAQ](http://customs.gov.au/faq/ProhibitedRestrictedGoods5.asp#Q351) for this:

> **Can I import Absinthe or oil of wormwood into Australia?**
>
> The controls
>   on the importation of ‘Oil of wormwood’ and products containing ‘oil
>   of wormwood’, have been repealed from the Customs (Prohibited Imports)
>   Regulations 1956.
>
> Permission is no longer required in order to import these products.

Here's [the official announcement](http://www.customs.gov.au/webdata/resources/files/ACN_2013_28.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

For several years, importing of Absinthe into Australia without permission was illegal - the product was restricted.  The reasons behind this was the ingredients:

"the import and sale of absinthe technically required a special permit, since "oil of wormwood, being an essential oil obtained from plants of the genus Artemisia, and preparations containing oil of wormwood" (wording: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Absinthe)) were listed as item 12A, Schedule 8, Regulation 5H  [Customs (Prohibited Imports) Regulations of 1956](http://www.comlaw.gov.au/Series/F1996B03651).

However, slowly, over time, laws changed.  The Food Standards Code and the 1989 Thereapeutic Goods Act set new terms on importing food, and as of July 2013, these rules have been [repealed](http://www.customs.gov.au/webdata/resources/files/ACN_2013_28.pdf) and now permission to import this item is [no longer required](http://customs.gov.au/faq/ProhibitedRestrictedGoods5.asp#Q351) (although some conditions exist).

Since the, the [Customs and Border Protection Service page](http://customs.gov.au/faq/ProhibitedRestrictedGoods5.asp#Q351) now states:

> Can I import Absinthe or oil of wormwood into Australia?
>
> The controls on the importation of ‘Oil of wormwood’ and products
>   containing ‘oil of wormwood’, have been repealed from the Customs
>   (Prohibited Imports) Regulations 1956.
>
> Permission is no longer required in order to import these products.
>
> If you are importing a product containing oil of wormwood for the
>   purpose of selling or distributing it in Australia, then you should
>   ensure that you comply with the Food Standards Code or the Therapeutic
>   Goods Act 1989
>
> For more information on these requirements, please use the contact
>   details below.
>
> Contact Details
>
> Therapeutic Goods Administration (TGA) Phone Local: 1800 020 653 Phone
>   International: +61 2 6232 8444 Email: eps@tga.gov.au Web:
>   www.tga.gov.au
>
> Food Standards Australia and New Zealand (FSANZ) Phone Local: (02)
>   6271 2222 Phone International:  +61 2 6271 2222 Email:
>   info@foodstandards.gov.au Web:  www.foodstandards.gov.au

Comment: Careful with the terminology there: it was not *illegal* (prohibited), it was only *restricted* (requires a permit).  While the permits were impractical for the average traveler, professionals can and did import absinthe legally.  Also, if you're going to quote what I just wrote on Wikipedia, please credit the source ;)

Comment: Sorry, you wrote on Wikipedia? Which bit? I went through a bunch of sites but thought I'd linked them all...

Comment: It was illegal without a permit, but you're right, I've clarified that.

Comment: "...technically required a special permit...", https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Absinthe&diff=609930517&oldid=609079718. And credit to WP, not me!

Comment: @jpatokal argh, sorry, I looked at the paragraph not realising I'd used two sources, and cited only one, thought I'd covered it. Updated now!